# OSGi Netty / Vertx error when running from bndtools/eclipse

Tags: maven, osgi, vert.x, bnd, bndtools

I am trying to run vertx under OSGi (bndtools/eclipse) and getting this error message from the underlying Netty.

I am using vertx 3.3.3
using bndtools in standalone mode (maven) so all dependencies are imported using maven and not the standard bndtools (cnf) template.

`17:00:05.935 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
17:00:05.938 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.level: simple
17:00:05.939 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.ResourceLeakDetector - -Dio.netty.leakDetection.maxRecords: 4
17:00:05.971 [main] DEBUG io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup - -Dio.netty.eventLoopThreads: 8
17:00:05.993 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 - java.nio.Buffer.address: available
17:00:05.994 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Platform: Windows
17:00:05.994 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - Java version: 8
17:00:05.994 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
17:00:05.995 [main] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent - maxDirectMemory: 3776970752 bytes (maybe)
! Failed to start bundle mybundle.vertx-2.0.0, exception activator error Could not initialize class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 from: io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent:<clinit>#101`

In my bundle activator I try to create a new vertx using the static method :

```

```
@Override
public void start(BundleContext bc) throws Exception {
   Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
```

```

In the standard bndtools template (none maven) this works fine. I am not sure I can mix the two modes in the same project and I prefer to stick to the maven format.

**EDIT**

I created this sample project cloned from the main Paremus project hello example to demonstrate the issue I am having with Vert.x & OSGi
https://github.com/gadieichhorn/hello-examples/tree/hello-1.13.x

**EDIT 2**

I moved the Vertx initialization to a service (not bundle activator) and now I am getting a more detailed error.

```
ERROR: helloworld-web (6): [com.example.hello.web.VertxRegistrationService(0)] The start method has thrown an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0
    at io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.<clinit>(PlatformDependent.java:101)
    at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:32)
    at io.netty.util.Signal$1.<init>(Signal.java:27)
    at io.netty.util.Signal.<clinit>(Signal.java:27)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.<clinit>(DefaultPromise.java:42)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:36)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventExecutorGroup.java:47)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.<init>(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:58)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:72)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.<init>(NioEventLoopGroup.java:59)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:133)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:122)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.<init>(VertxImpl.java:118)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxFactoryImpl.vertx(VertxFactoryImpl.java:34)
    at io.vertx.core.Vertx.vertx(Vertx.java:80)
    at com.example.hello.web.VertxRegistrationService.lambda$0(VertxRegistrationService.java:26)
    at com.example.hello.web.TcclSwitch.executeWithTCCLSwitch(TcclSwitch.java:11)
    at com.example.hello.web.VertxRegistrationService.start(VertxRegistrationService.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invokeMethod(BaseMethod.java:222)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.access$500(BaseMethod.java:37)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod$Resolved.invoke(BaseMethod.java:615)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.BaseMethod.invoke(BaseMethod.java:499)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.helper.ActivateMethod.invoke(ActivateMethod.java:295)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createImplementationObject(SingleComponentManager.java:302)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.createComponent(SingleComponentManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getService(SingleComponentManager.java:866)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.SingleComponentManager.getServiceInternal(SingleComponentManager.java:833)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.activateInternal(AbstractComponentManager.java:724)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.manager.AbstractComponentManager.enable(AbstractComponentManager.java:399)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurableComponentHolder.enableComponents(ConfigurableComponentHolder.java:676)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.BundleComponentActivator.initialEnable(BundleComponentActivator.java:339)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.loadComponents(Activator.java:360)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.access$000(Activator.java:53)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator$ScrExtension.start(Activator.java:260)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.addingBundle(AbstractExtender.java:192)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:469)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(BundleTracker.java:415)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackInitial(AbstractTracked.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker.open(BundleTracker.java:156)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.startTracking(AbstractExtender.java:150)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.doStart(AbstractExtender.java:142)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.doStart(Activator.java:170)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.start(AbstractExtender.java:114)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.restart(Activator.java:140)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ScrConfiguration.configure(ScrConfiguration.java:215)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ScrConfiguration.start(ScrConfiguration.java:136)
    at org.apache.felix.scr.impl.Activator.start(Activator.java:110)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:697)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2226)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2144)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:483)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.activate(Launcher.java:382)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:276)
    at aQute.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:133)
```

any help appreciated

Comment: bndtools 3.4.0.DEV with m2e plugins enabled

Comment: It looks like there should be more of that error message. It stops just as it's getting interesting.

Comment: @NeilBartlett I am afraid this is all there is in the console.

Comment: That's a shame. The failure to initialise a class should have an underlying cause, which may be NCDFE or similar. Is it possible to debug into the code, or turn on additional logging?

Answer (score 1):

It is because "PlatformDependent0" import "sun.misc".

You can solve this by setting `"org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=sun.misc"`

EDIT 1 :

I start the OSGi framework (Apache Felix) this way :

```
Map<String, String> configProperties = Main.loadConfigProperties();
Main.copySystemProperties(configProperties);
configProperties.put("org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra","sun.misc");
Framework fw = new Felix(configProperties);
fw.init();
AutoProcessor.process(configProperties, fw.getBundleContext());
```

But I guess you can directly put this setting in the `"felix.config.properties"` file.

The problems occurs because `sun.misc` is private API. So you have to explicitly add the package as an extra package provided by the Main Bundle. It is done implicitly for public API (java.lang, java.util...)

Comment: thanks @alex29260, can you be more specific? you mean in the bnd file? can you provide a full example? thanks.

Comment: @Gadi I don't use bnb. I updated my answer. Hope it helps